# why magento2 choose adaptive web design?

Tags: magento2, rwd, design

As we know website can be developed either **Responsive Web Design**(RWD) or **Adaptive Web Design** (AWD).

**RWD:** No matter what the browser width may be, the site adjusts its layout

**AWD:** Adapt to the width of the browser at a specific points

is there any reason behind with magento choose AWD?

[magento2 official documents](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/responsive-web-design/rwd_overview.html) refer magento2 use **RWD**. I felt which is not correct, **RWD** does not bother about break points (screen height and width). If I'm wrong please correct me.